# Convert Dynamic JSON to PDF and XML in React

Tags: reactjs, json, flask, pdf, type-conversion

In my project, I'm using ReactJS as a frontend and Flask for Backend.
Here's a code I wrote to Get a case's details in the from of JSON and also convert it to Pretty JSON.

I now require a download button with which I can take the JSON input and download it as JSON, PDF and XML.

Here's the code-
**CaseTree.js**

```
        <Grid item xs={12} md={10} className={classes.rightUpperPart}>

                    {/* Render CaseTree in Pretty Json format */}
                    {
                        (caseReducer.isLoading || !caseReducer.caseTree ||fileReducer.isLoading || !fileReducer.file || !fileReducer.fileType) ? (
                            <JsonPretty data={caseReducer.caseTree}/>
                        ) : (fileReducer.fileType === 'report' || fileReducer.fileType === 'txt') ? (
                            <ShowTXT data={fileReducer.file} className={classes.rightPart}/>
                        ) : (fileReducer.fileType === 'tsv') ? (
                            <ShowTSV data={fileReducer.file} className={classes.rightPart}/>) : (
                                <pre className={classes.preStyle}>{fileReducer.file}</pre>
                            )
                    }

                </Grid>
**ADD DOWNLOAD BUTTON HERE**
```

**JSON Pretty File**

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
    Box,
    Typography
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';


// custom styles
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: '#1f4662',
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: '12px',
        overflow: 'auto',
        padding: theme.spacing(4),
        height: theme.spacing(55),
    },
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '193549',
        fontFamily: 'monospace',
        color: '#ffc600',
    },
    preStyle: {
        display: 'block',
        padding: '10px 3px',
        margin: '0',
        color: '#fff'
    }
}))
function JsonPretty({data}) {

    // invoke custom styles
    const classes = useStyles()

    // get case Reducer
    const caseReducer = useSelector(state => state.case)

    // default json data
    const defaultData = {
        "processing": ( caseReducer.isLoading ) ? "Wait Processing..." : "Done",
        "success": false,
        "message": ( caseReducer.error ) ? caseReducer.error : "Please Provide a Case Name.",
    }

    return (
        <Box component="div" className={classes.root}>
            <Typography className={classes.headerStyle}>
                Pretty Json Format
            </Typography>

            {
                (data) ? (
                    <pre className={classes.preStyle}>
                        {JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}
                    </pre>
                ) : (
                    <pre className={classes.preStyle}>
                        {JSON.stringify(defaultData, null, 4)}
                    </pre>
                )
            }
        </Box>
    )
}

export default JsonPretty
```

**LoadCaseTree def**

```
export const loadCaseTree = (case_name) => (dispatch) => {

    //// dispatch laod case
    dispatch({
        type: LOAD_CASE_TREE
    })

    //// Create request data body
    const data = {
        case_name: case_name
    }

    //// Get token from localstorage
    const token = localStorage.getItem('openmf_token')

    //// add headers
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }

    //// If token available add to headers
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: LOAD_CASE_TREE_FAILED })
      dispatch(setAlert('Please Log In.'))
      return
    }

    //// Send request to server
    axios.post('/case/case-tree', data, config)
        .then((res) => {
            const case_tree_json = JSON.parse(res.data.tree)
            dispatch({
                type: LOAD_CASE_TREE_SUCCESSFULL,
                payload: {
                  tree: case_tree_json,
                  case: res.data.case
                }
            })
            dispatch(setAlert(res.data.message, 'success'))
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            const res = err.response

            //// check err status code
            if(res && (res.status === 404 || res.status === 422 || res.status === 500)){
              dispatch({
                type: LOAD_CASE_TREE_FAILED,
                payload: {
                  error: res.data.message
                }
              })
              dispatch(setAlert(res.data.message))
              return
            }

            //// FOr unknown reason
            dispatch({
              type: LOAD_CASE_TREE_FAILED,
              payload: {
                error: 'Something went wrong.'
              }
            })

            //// dispatch alert
            dispatch(setAlert('Something went wrong.'))
        })

}
```

Please let me know if I've missed out on any code snippet or information.